# How do I fade out a rectangle over a given time interval in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, animation, graphics

I am writing a Cocoa application for OS X, where the user can draw squares on an `NSView` instance by clicking with the mouse. Currently I am making the squares disappear after 2 seconds, using the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method of `NSObject`, to force a redraw of the view, with no square included.

However, instead of just disappearing, I would like the squares to fade out gradually. I've tried using an `NSTimer` to periodically force a redraw, with the opacity of the square decreasing to 0 over 2 seconds, but this seems rather inelegant and probably inefficient, especially if I have a lot of squares.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

**UPDATE**: just to clarify, I want each square drawn in the view to have an independent fade starting from the point at which it's drawn, I'm not looking to fade out the entire view.

Comment: If you are drawing with NSBezierPath or NSRect you should be able to set the color property of your path or rect with NSColor: yourObjectOneColor = [NSColor color:(float)0.0 green:(float)0.0 blue:(float)0.0 alpha:(float)1.0]; So try animating to an alpha of 0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've ended up using is to create a `CALayer` instance for each square, rather than using `NSRectFill` to draw the squares. The opacity of each `CALayer` instance can then be independently animated using a `CABasicAnimation` instance. E.g.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.]];
[animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.]];
[animation setDuration:2.];
[layer setOpacity:0.];
[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacity"];
```

Answer (score 0):

[NSAnimationContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSAnimationContext_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: `NSAnimationContext` looks handy, but turned out to be overkill for what I needed. `CABasicAnimation` sufficed (see above).